# Excel: Sum partial weeks for EOM report

Tags: excel, date

I'm looking for a formula that will let me get a weekly total of a daily totals column during partial weeks at the end month for Excel 2010. Using the US week of Monday-Friday.

I have a Day(A), Date(B), Daily Total(J) and Weekly Total(N) column for one month. I'd like to show the totals for the week (M-F) either on Fridays, or the last day of the month. For full weeks, if the Day="Fri", I can sum column J by using a 5 cell range like $J11-$J15 which would sum the daily totals from Monday thru Friday of a full week in the middle of the month.

That doesn't work for a partial week at the beginning, so I have modified versions for the first 5 days, if a Friday is detected and that seems to work. I'm open to other ideas if there's a better way to handle the first week.

```
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
    A    B         J   (N) Week
 1 Day Date      Total  Total      Formula for Column N Week Total
 2 Thu 1/1/2015   1                 =IF($A2="Fri",$J2,"")
 3 Fri 1/2/2015   2      3          =IF($A3="Fri",SUM($J$2:$J3),"")
 4                                  =IF($A4="Fri",SUM($J$2:$J4),"")
 5                                  =IF($A5="Fri",SUM($J$2:$J5),"")
 6                                  =IF($A6="Fri",SUM($J$2:$J6),"")
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

A6/N6 would be the last possible Friday for the first 5 days of the first week, so the rest of the formulas, until towards the end of the month are similar to:

```
 N7 would be =IF($A7="Fri",SUM($J3:$J7),"")
 N8 would be =IF($A8="Fri",SUM($J4:$J8),"")
```

It handles summing a 5 day full week, in the middle of the month, and only shows the weekly total in column N for Fridays.

I don't know how to handle the last week since it could be a partial week of between 1-4 weekdays, not ending on a Friday. I still want show a total for that last partial week, on the last weekday of the month.

I thought about checking to see if the days in the last week were either Friday or the end of the month, and came up with a check for either "Fri" or the end of the month. For example in January day 31 would be:

```
 (N32)  =IF(OR($A32="Fri",EOMONTH($B$2,0)=$B32),SUM($J28:$J32),"")
```

That works if and only if, the 31st is a Fri, but doesn't work if Jan 31st is a Mon-Thurs since the range to sum is fixed at 5 days ($J28:$J32) and I don't know how to make it variable, based on how many days are in that last week of the month.

I would appreciate your ideas on how to do a monthly report where it can show weekly totals for full or partial weeks. The "plan" is to have 4 empty master workbooks to use for months with 28, 29, 30 and 31 days since I don't know how to make it all purpose and not screw up borders.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your data include `Saturdays` or `Sundays`? I'm assuming not. If not then you need to check whether the date is the last **workday** of the month....or a Friday.....and you could just sum everything in column J up to that point and subtract the column N totals form above, i.e. in N2 copied down

`=IF(B2="","",IF(OR(A2="Fri",MONTH(WORKDAY(B2,1))<>MONTH(B2)),SUM(J$2:J2)-SUM(N$1:N1),""))`

I assume `N1` will contain a text header

Comment: No Saturdays or Sundays. Just data on Mondays through Fridays. Cool stuff for sure. That did what I needed. Thank you.